# ffmpeg: How to burn in the timecode from a stream's metadata

Tags: ffmpeg, timecode

I have a timelapse video from a GoPro and want to overlay the time of the recording on the current frame. For instance, a frame taken at 9am might show `09:00`.

It seems like [the `drawtext` filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) is the way to go. I'm struggling to figure out the right invocation to grab the right time and make that work.

ffprobe shows that there's a `timecode` attached to each individual stream, but not the input's overall metadata:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'GX010246.MP4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp41
    minor_version   : 538120216
    compatible_brands: mp41
    creation_time   : 2022-11-01T23:24:04.000000Z
    firmware        : H22.01.01.12.00
  Duration: 00:00:00.23, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 106869 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 5312x2988 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 105367 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-11-01T23:24:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro H.265
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : GoPro H.265 encoder
      timecode        : 09:23:30:08
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-11-01T23:24:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro TCD
      timecode        : 09:23:30:08
  Stream #0:2[0x3](eng): Data: bin_data (gpmd / 0x646D7067), 408 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2022-11-01T23:24:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : GoPro MET
```

To make it even harder, this timecode is the *end* of the recording - when it was saved - so the timestamp on each frame has to be `((timecode from metadata) - (clip duration) + (time since start))`.

### Some attempts

This is a start, which overlays the local time when ffmpeg was run:

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%{localtime\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460: fontsize=96" out.mp4
```

This can't find `timecode`, maybe because it's not defined:

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%{timecode\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460: fontsize=96" out.mp4
```

This tries to reference `metadata:s:v:0:timecode`, but the reference is invalid somehow, even with [the right amount of escaping](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729560):

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='%{metadata\\\\\\:s\\\\\\:v\\\\\\:0\\\\\\:timecode}': r=29.97 : fontcolor=white@0.8:fontsize=96" out.mp4
```

The [pts](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion) function could work, but I can't figure out how to invoke it or pass it the start time

There's also `drawtext=timecode=<start timecode>`, which seems promising:

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=timecode='00\:00\:00\:00': r=29.97 : fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460: fontsize=96" out.mp4
```

but I also haven't figured out how to put this dynamic data into it:

```sh
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=timecode='%{s:v:0:timecode}': r=29.97 : fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460: fontsize=96" out.mp4
# fails
```

Would really appreciate some help with this tricky problem!

Answer (score 0):

A colleague just pointed this out to me

```
-vf "drawtext=text='%{metadata\:timecode}':box=1:boxcolor=black:fontcolor=white:fontsize=48:x=100:y=100"
```

Works with both timecode in SEI & MXF timecode track
NB: Doesn't work with ffmpeg 4